# td border disappears when applying transform translate

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a table with a fixed header and a fixed first column.

The header and column stay fixed by applying transform translateX/Y on the scroll event.

When the page loads, the borders are visible on the top row but once you scroll down a little bit they disappear.

What CSS do I need to not let the border disappear?

A plunker with the source can be found [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/abvXiUqYD5LKCRb2xmtQ/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across with similar situation and adding `border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 0px;` to table fixed this.

> border-collapse: separate; -: this set separate border for table cells and if its border-collapse: collapse; then cells share their border.

when we translate, only the cells move which share their border and that cause the problem.

```
table.scroll {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById("table-container").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;

});
```

```css
thead, tr, th, td, tbody{
 border: 1px solid;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3px;
 
}
table.scroll {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
th{
 background-color:#99ccff;
 height: 40px;
 font-size: 20px;

}

tr{
 width: 500%;
 height: 20px;
 font-size: 17px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #CCFFFF;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #fae8d1;
}

#table-container{
 float:left;
 height: 200px;
 border: 2px solid;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-container">
 <table class="scroll">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="col-md-2">Name</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Birthday</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Gender</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Marital</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Address</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Telephone</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Email</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps