# Javascript - scroll event stop element scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code pen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLaqLz

Its a table that scrolls left/right and up/down.

When scrolling up/down I want the headers to be sticky.

This simple javascript is the best way I have found to do this.

The header has a border along the bottom that should be sticky when the content scrolls.

I thought I could set the border with css in the javascriot when scrolling but it seems to break the scrolling

Can anyone see why the border scrolls and how tos top it scrolling.

```
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  var myElements = this.querySelectorAll("thead");
  //myElements.style.border = '2px solid red';
  for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.transform=translate;
  }
});
```

Comment: it breaks your scrolling because not correct. You should set this border using `myElements[i].style` in the loop for it to work. However, the border doesn't follow the header with the translation, and probably shouldn't be set at each scroll event (so didn't write an answer)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692744/td-border-disappears-when-applying-transform-translate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [td border disappears when applying transform translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692744/td-border-disappears-when-applying-transform-translate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this answer [td border disappears when applying transform translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692744/td-border-disappears-when-applying-transform-translate), problem comes beause of how borders are treated on tables.

A table will merge borders on cells, so when the `border-bottom` property of the thead is actually shared with the bottom cell.

The mentioned answer suggested using `border-collapse: separate;`, but in your case, you may get away using `outline` instead of `border`.

```js
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  var myElements = this.querySelectorAll("thead");
  //myElements.style.border = '2px solid red';
  for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.transform=translate;
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.page{
  background: white;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.table-con{
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
} 

table{
  /*table-layout: fixed;*/
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  width: 1500px;
}

thead th:first-child{
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

th{
  text-align: left;
}

thead{
  background: white;
  outline: 3px solid red;
}

tbody td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:not(:first-child){
  background: yellow;
}

tbody td:first-child{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

th, td{
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="table-con" id="table">
<!--     <div class="white-block"></div>
    <div class="white-block white-block-1"></div> -->
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
          <th>Header 5</th>
          <th>Header 6</th>
          <th>Header 7</th>
          <th>Header 8</th>
          <th>Header 9</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>  
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I change `thead` style to

```
thead{
      background-color: red;
      background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Solid_white.svg/2000px-Solid_white.svg.png');
      background-size: 100% 96%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  var myElements = this.querySelectorAll("thead");
  //myElements.style.border = '2px solid red';
  for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.transform=translate;
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.page{
  background: white;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.table-con{
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
} 

table{
  /*table-layout: fixed;*/
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  width: 1500px;
}

thead th:first-child{
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  
}

th{
  text-align: left;
}

thead{
   background-color: red;
  background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Solid_white.svg/2000px-Solid_white.svg.png');
     background-size: 100% 96%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

 
}

tbody td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:not(:first-child){
  background: yellow;
}

tbody td:first-child{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

th, td{
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="table-con" id="table">
<!--     <div class="white-block"></div>
    <div class="white-block white-block-1"></div> -->
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
          <th>Header 5</th>
          <th>Header 6</th>
          <th>Header 7</th>
          <th>Header 8</th>
          <th>Header 9</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>  
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 
</div>
```

The updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Brqyxg